# How many times in a 24 hour day do the minute and hour hand make a 90 degree angle?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

I am really curious about ways to tackle this since it is such an open ended problem.

I thought about it purely visually and after an embarrassingly long time figured out the answer to be

> \begin{align*} 44 \end{align*}

I would love to hear how others think about it! I have also found a neat "rigorized" solution I would be happy to share.

Comment: that is not embarrassing! to most people, these kinds of specific problems tend to be easily but slowly solvable

Comment: I think that's what makes them frustrating. I think it's easy to hide behind lots of machinery in higher math

Comment: You could sit in front of a clock for 24 hours and count.

Comment: not the most elegant, but hey, that's just like, my opinion

Comment: Yes, 'higher math' (like category theoretic constructions, abstract group theory etc.) tends to be free of conventions, and so, in the end, when all the fear of abstraction settles, is easier than this kind of problems. This kind of problems ask you: given this and this particular convention, what can you say about that?

Comment: @Will Jagy this is the most awesome answer I have see ever ..oll

Comment: Answer may be 48

Comment: @SathasivamK it is not

Comment: Well,its 44...but how?

Comment: @SathasivamK check the linked answer, some of those are quite good

Comment: I check it already.but for every hours you have 2 right angle then totally 48 .but they give answer as 44 . I'm confused.@qbert

Comment: what about for 3 oclock or 9 oclock?

Comment: (1/2)
Although this seems quite simple at first, it's deceptively tricky to conceptualise. Try thinking about how many times the hands cross.

As was stated in the other question, you can reason that since the hour hand, $H$, rotates once in a $12$ hour period but the minute hand, $M$, rotates $12$ times, you can say that from the perspective of $H$, there are just $12-1=11$ rotations of $M$. So $H$ and $M$ cross $11$ times...

Comment: (2/2)
You could also reason this as finding the places where the tips of $H$ and $M$ cross on a clockface on the unit circle centre $(0,0)$. i.e. solving $(\sin(t),\cos(t))=(\sin(12t),\cos(12t))$, which gives you $11$ solutions: $t\in\{0,\frac{2\pi}{11},\dots,\frac{11\cdot2\pi}{11}\}$.

For each of our solutions where the hands cross, $M$ is perpendicular to $H$ exactly twice, when it is on the left and when on the right. Hence, our total number of solutions is $2\cdot2\cdot11=44$.